# What is a save to file symbol on a flowchart

Tags: computer-science, diagram, flowchart

I am currently doing practice coursework for my GCSE Computer Science, and I need to create a flowchart to show my code. In the code, I have a few sections where it either writes or reads from files. There is also a section where it automatically prints a file.

Do any of you know what flowchart symbols would represent these three functions. If so, what are they?

Thanks :)

Comment: Flowcharts, really!? (-:

Comment: @tripleee Indeed! It must be 35 years since I last produced one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Indicates a step where data gets stored]

Data Storage or Stored Data Symbol

Indicates a step where data gets stored.
Edit: Damn, didn't read the rest of the question, just the headline.

The document symbol represents the input or output of a document.
[image: Print document]

Comment: Can you also use that to show that the program is reading data off of a file?

Comment: @AdamBromiley The direction of the flow of information is always provided by the arrows .

Answer (score -1):

That would probably be the Direct Data Access symbol. It looks like the cylindrical database symbol, but on its side.